# DirectoryNotFoundException when running from PCs other than Server in C#

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

I have developed a console application which zips up files within a directory with password to a destination folder.
I am zipping files within a directory to a destination folder with password.

This is the code. In my local PC its working fine. I have created setup for this application and installed on my PC as well as other PCs too. In my PC its working fine. but on other PCs its giving exception. 
Can you please tell me what could be the issue and how should I solve it?
Is this permission related issue or some other issue.

```
{
    int codePage = 0;
    ZipEntry e = null;
    string entryComment = null;
    string entryDirectoryPathInArchive = "";
    string strFullFilePath = "";
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        //zip.ExtractExistingFile= ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently;
        // zip.ExtractAll(Environment.CurrentDirectory, .OverwriteSilently);
        //var result = zipFile.Any(entry => entry.FileName.EndsWith("input.txt"));

        zip.StatusMessageTextWriter = System.Console.Out;
        zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (args[i])
            {
                case "-p":
                    i++;
                    if (args.Length <= i) Usage();
                    zip.Password = (args[i] == "") ? null : args[i];
                    break;

                case "-flat":
                    entryDirectoryPathInArchive = "";
                    break;

                        //case "-utf8":
                        //    zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary = true;
                        //    break;

                case "-64":
                    zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.Always;
                    break;

                case "-d":
                    i++;
                    if (args.Length <= i) Usage();
                    string entryName = args[i];

                    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(args[i]))
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(args[i]);

                        //System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Path ({0}) does not exist.", strFullFilePath);
                        //m_log.Error("Destination Path "+strFullFilePath+" does not exist.");
                    }

                    System.DateTime Timestamp = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
                    string strFileName = Timestamp.ToShortDateString();
                    strFullFilePath = args[i] + strFileName + ".zip";
                    break;

                case "-c":
                    i++;
                    if (args.Length <= i) Usage();
                    entryComment = args[i];  // for the next entry
                    break;

                case "-zc":
                    i++;
                    if (args.Length <= i) Usage();
                    zip.Comment = args[i];
                    break;

                case "-cp":
                    i++;
                    if (args.Length <= i) Usage();
                    System.Int32.TryParse(args[i], out codePage);
                    if (codePage != 0)
                        zip.ProvisionalAlternateEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(codePage);
                    break;

                case "-s":
                    i++;
                    if (args.Length <= i) Usage();
                    zip.AddDirectory(args[i], args[i]);
                    //entryDirectoryPathInArchive = args[i];
                    break;

                default:
                    // UpdateItem will add Files or Dirs, recurses subdirectories
                    //zip.UpdateItem(args[i], entryDirectoryPathInArchive);

                    // try to add a comment if we have one
                    if (entryComment != null)
                    {
                        // can only add a comment if the thing just added was a file.
                        if (zip.EntryFileNames.Contains(args[i]))
                        {
                            e = zip[args[i]];
                            e.Comment = entryComment;
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("Warning: ZipWithEncryption.exe: ignoring comment; cannot add a comment to a directory.");

                        // reset the comment
                        entryComment = null;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            zip.Save(strFullFilePath);
        }
    }
```

These are the exception messages

```
Saving....
Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the pa
th.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String zipFileName)
   at Ionic.Zip.Examples.ZipWithEncryption.Main(String[] args)
Exception:
Exception: Could not find a part of the path.
Exception: mscorlib
Exception:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullP
ath)
   at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String zipFileName)
   at Ionic.Zip.Examples.ZipWithEncryption.Main(String[] args)
Exception: Void WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
```

Comment: probably the client machine don´t have that directory. take a look at this

Comment: You probably lack permissions

Comment: You only seem to check if the directory exists when the '-d' argument is used. Shouldn't you always perform this check (i.e. take it outside of the argument loop)?

Comment: what are the arguments ?

Comment: these are the arguments -p nuna -s D:\Source -d D:\Destination\

Comment: if this issue is related to permission then how to solve it ?

Comment: You should probably log out what the directory is (and what directory is created). Also, might be worth using 'Path.Combine()' in case the directories are not supplied with a trailing '\'.

Comment: Creating strFullFilePath with `+` is a bad idea. Use `Path.Combine(...)` instead. TimeStamp is strange, why don't you write `DateTime TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;` ?

Comment: I think you have different CurrentCulture. So ToShortDateString() return different string, and may be with a "/".

Comment: I agree with @Xaruth. I was able to reproduce your problem and then fix with the change he suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code is strange :

```
System.DateTime Timestamp = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
string strFileName = Timestamp.ToShortDateString();
strFullFilePath = args[i] + strFileName + ".zip";
```

First, you can write

```
DateTime Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
```

Then `ToShortDateString` depend on CurrentCulture. Force what you want (for exemple :)

```
String strFileName = Timestamp.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Exception is from here, on my mind. With wrong Culture, you can have "/" in your format string.

Then, use `Path.Combine` instead of operator + (no error with a missing slash)

```
strFullFilePath = Path.Combine(args[i], strFileName + ".zip");
```

**Edit**
For those who can't format DateTime, here my code (and that works) :

```
public static class Constantes
{
    public const String DateTimePattern = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
}

public class SaveProcessViewModel : NotificationObject
{
[...]
    String zipFileName = System.Environment.MachineName + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString(Constantes.DateTimePattern) + ".zip";
    String tempZipFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), zipFileName);

    zip.Save(tempZipFile);
[...]
}
```

Comment: Your format specified should be "yyyyMMdd" - MM is month, yours has mm = minutes.

Comment: I did it by memory. Never remember wich is upper or lower ^^

Comment: Not working in my case. I have done changes as suggested by you.

Comment: Commented DateTime code and its working fine. it means it was issue related to culture. Now If I want that zip file should be created with the date. how to set it

Comment: See my edit. Use `ToString("yyyyMMdd")` or something like that to format your DateTime.